# Firefox websocket opening handshake

Tags: firefox, websocket

I am writing a very basic websocket server. This works in Google Chrome but not in Firefox (v46.0.1). The error message in Firefox is not very helpful either.

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at
>   ws://localhost:9000/.

This is the Opening handshake from firefox.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ZfChFbbco7cR0jrAliH+LQ==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

This is my server's opening handshake response.

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: <accept-key>
```

Is the server's opening response not enough for Firefox?

Comment: It should work with those headers. And `Sec-WebSocket-Version` is not needed in the response and also there is no need to keep `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` a secret, its purpose isn't authorization/identification.

Comment: No, I did not mean to make Sec-WebSocket-Accept a secret . It is meant to be a variable. I copied that from my code, that's how the response is constructed.

Comment: I have read somewhere that It does not work because Connection has two values but haven't tried anything yet. Does it expect some more in the response header?

Comment: The response headers are fine.

Comment: did find any solution for this?